# Tons of issues with Alamofire when compiling xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I was running my program softly and at some point (maybe closed the Xcode to reopen or updated pod file) it suddenly it can't compile anymore.

I already tried opening .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace. The first one shows this message when compiling:

[image: xcodeproj]

The second case shows tons of issues:

[image: xcworkspace]

This is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'HonoluluArt' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks



  # Pods for HonoluluArt
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'

    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

Can I get any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm using swift 4 by the way

Comment: Alamofire v3 may not work with Swift 4. You may want to update to Alamofire v5.

Comment: I just don't get it... It was working before this...

Comment: @onnoweb I tried, but got this:

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire":
  In Podfile:
    Alamofire (~> 5.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Alamofire (~> 5.0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed any reference to Alamofire. Pod file, imports, paths and stuff and it worked. I'm trying to manage the code once it is removed, but worked.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

try to clear pods and reinstall:

1. in the project folder execute: `pod deintegrate`
2. then clean pods: `pod clean`
3. Reinstall pods: `pod install`

this should work

also if you don't need in particular the v3 of `Alamofire` remove `~> 3` to install the latest version and modify your Podfile:

```
target 'HonoluluArt' do
use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

Comment: didn't work... terminal printed there is no command pod clean and printed this with pod install:
[!] The `HonoluluArt [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HonoluluArt/Pods-HonoluluArt.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

and some errors like this, but ain't no characters left to post.

Comment: Nothing changed, unfortunately, still got tons of erros when using .xcworkspace and that "framework not found Alamofire" when using .xcodeproj.

Answer (score 0):

`Alamofire ~> 3.0` is written in `Swift 3`. `Podfile` shows that this is an older codebase. You could try building you project with older version of Xcode (`xCode 10.0` is last version supporting `Swift 3`) or you should upgrade `Alamofire` to actual version `~> 5.0` (you will also need to upgrade project codebase to newer `Swift` version).

Answer (score 0):

You indicated you opened the project file and compiled.  Cocoa Pod instructions clearly state after installing, you should only work in the .xcworkspace file thereafter.  Can you open that and try a compile?

Comment: I just removed any reference to Alamofire and it worked, and yes, I'm using .xcworksapce... I'm looking how to manage things from now once I removed the Alamofire. Will close this.